# How to remove shadow overlay on drawer navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I have created a side menu using drawer navigation. i am getting shadow overlay on the back view. I want to remove the shadow overlay.

Here is what I am getting right now. you see that I am getting a shadow overlay over my view when the drawer is open.

[image]

Here is what I want I want the view to be no shadow over the view.

[image]

please find below my code which creates a side menu using drawer navigation.

```
// Drawer.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './AppNavigation';
import { SideMenu } from "./../Common/UIComponents";
import { widthScale } from "./../Common/Utils/Scaling";

export default DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Home },
    MyAccount: { screen: () => <View /> },
    MessageToBigFm: { screen: () => <View /> },
    MeetTheMJs: { screen: () => <View /> },
    Videos: { screen: () => <View /> },
    AboutUs: { screen: () => <View /> },
    ContactUs: { screen: () => <View /> },
    TermsAndConditions: { screen: () => <View /> }
}, {
        contentComponent: SideMenu,
        drawerWidth: widthScale(320),
        drawerBackgroundColor: "transparent",
        style: { backgroundColor: "transparent", opacity: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowColor: "transparent" }
    });
```

Side menu js file

```
// SideMenu.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, ScrollView, Platform } from "react-native";
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import style from "./style";
import SideMenuHeader from "./SideMenuHeader";
import { ListFlat } from "./../../UIComponents";
import SideMenuData from "./SideMenuData";
import SideMenuCell from "./SideMenuCell";
import NavigationUtil from "./../../Utils/NavigationUtil";

class SideMenu extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.navigateToScreenWithIndex =     this.navigateToScreenWithIndex.bind(this);
    this.renderItemSeperator = this.renderItemSeperator.bind(this)
}

navigateToScreenWithIndex(index) {
    const routeData = SideMenuData[index];
    if (!routeData) {
        return null;
    }
    const routeKey = routeData.navigationKey;
    if (routeKey === null) {
        return;
    }
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: routeKey })
        ]
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}

renderItemSeperator({ leadingItem }) {
    if (leadingItem.key === 4) {
        return <View style={style.seperator} />
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={style.container}>
            {Platform.OS === "ios" && <View style={style.statusBar} />}
            <View style={style.listContainer}>
                <ListFlat
                    horizontal={false}
                    renderHeader={() => <SideMenuHeader />}
                    data={SideMenuData}
                    CellComponent={SideMenuCell}
                    otherProps={{ onCellPress: this.navigateToScreenWithIndex }}
                    renderSeparator={this.renderItemSeperator}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
    }
}

export default SideMenu;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation where React's Material UI adds a "MuiBackdrop-root" class div upon showing the Drawer. This was on web, but a mobile version of styled-components exists for React-Native--it could work.

Using the [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) library, I used a CSS property similar to the following to hide it using "display: none". You have to use the > to directly target the element.

Something like this:

```
const MyDrawer = styled(Drawer)`
 & > .MuiBackdrop-root {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `overlayColor="transparent"` property to `screenOptions` of `Drawer.Navigator`.